# Does compact orbit imply periodicity?

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

A continuous dynamical system on a metric space $X$ is given by:

> $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \times X \rightarrow X$ - continuous s.t.
>
> $\varphi (0,x) = x$ for every $x \in X$
>
> $\varphi (t, \varphi(s,x) ) = \varphi(s+t, x)$ for all $s, t \in
> \mathbb{R}, \ \ x \in X $

and

> $\gamma(x) = \{y \in X| \exists t\in \mathbb{R}; \varphi(t,x) = y \}$
>   is the *orbit* of $x$.
>
> $x \in X$ is *periodic* iff $x =\varphi(T,x)$ for some $0 \neq T \in \mathbb
>  R$.

---

The *question* is the following:

> Assume that $x$ is periodic. Show that $\gamma(x)$ is compact. **Is the converse true?**

---

For the first part, if $x$ is periodic of period $T \ge 0$ then $\gamma(x)= \varphi (\{x\} \times[-T,T])$ which is an image of a compact set, hence compact.

However, I am not sure about the converse. All I know is that for some sequence $t_n \to \infty$, $\varphi(t_n,x) \to x'$ for some $x' \in \gamma(x)$. Hence $\exists t' \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi (t',x) = x'$. On the other hand, we also have a continuous bijection from $\mathbb R$ to a compact set. At first sight this does not seem enough though.

Thank you.

P.S. The problem is from Bhattia & Szego: Stability Theory of Dynamical Systems

Comment: Yes, see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391315/are-closed-orbits-of-lie-group-action-embedded/2216157#2216157

Comment: also seems related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169592/aode-compact-orbit-iff-periodic

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for the much more general answer. Because of my lack of topological group knowledge, in the meantime, I have come up with and written up a somewhat detailed solution to the particular case. Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer of @Moishe Kohan answers an even more general question, in the meantime I was able to solve the particular problem (hopefully correctly). It makes use of the Baire category theorem and the following two lemmas:

---

> **Lemma 1.** Assume that the $x$ is not periodic and $\gamma(x)$ is compact. Then for any $x' \in\gamma(x) $ there exists a real sequence $(T_n) , T_n \to \infty$ such
> that $\varphi(T_n, x) \to x'$.

*Proof*: Noticing that due to compactness, the sequence $(\varphi(n,x))_n$ converges up to a subsequence, denote its limit as $x'' \in \gamma(x)$ (i.e. $\varphi(n(k), x) \to_{k \to \infty} x''$ for some subsequence $(n(k))_k$ of $(n)_n$). Because $x'' \in \gamma(x)$, $\exists T $ such that $x'= \varphi(T,x'')$. Now setting $(T_k)_k = (T+n(k))_k$, one can notice that $\varphi(T_k,x) \to x'$. $\square$

Applying **Lemma 1** and $(\text{compactness} \implies \text{closedness}) + (\text{continuous image of a compact set is compact})$ in metric spaces, one can obtain:

> **Lemma 2.** Assume that the $x$ is not periodic and $\gamma(x)$ is compact. For any integer $n$, the set $\varphi([n,n+1],x)$ is closed and of empty interior in $\gamma(x)$.

---

Now for the sake of contradiction, assume that $x$ is not periodic. Remarking that $$\gamma(x) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \varphi([n,n+1],x), $$ according to **Lemma 2** and the Baire category theorem (notice that $\text{compactness of } \gamma(x) \implies \text{completeness of } \gamma(x)$), the right hand side should be of empty interior in $\gamma(x)$. This is the desired contradiction.